# Jasper report server community edition and PHP client

Tags: php, client, jasperserver

I have deployed Jasper report Server community edition on server 192.168.1.107 running on Windows 7. I can log in on this PC and run reports.

I have an Apache web server on 192.168.1.10 with PHP.

I have deployed the Jasper PHP client in the Apache server.

I have the following script built from the example code.

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
header('Content-Type: text/html');
use Jaspersoft\Client\Client;
$c = new Client(
                "http://192.168.1.107:8080/jasperserver",
                "jasperadmin",
                "my_password",
                ""
            );
$info = $c->serverInfo();
print_r($info);
?>
```

When I run the PHP I get the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException' with message 'An unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server' in C:\xampp\htdocs\courierserver\fsumanager\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php:378
>
> Stack trace: 
>    #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\courierserver\fsumanager\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php(451): Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest->handleError(0, Array, false) 
>    #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\courierserver\fsumanager\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Client\Client.php(158): Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest->prepAndSend('http://192.168....', Array, 'GET', NULL, true, 'application/jso...', 'application/jso...')  
>    #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\courierserver\fsumanager\abc_report2.php(15): Jaspersoft\Client\Client->serverInfo() 
>    #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\courierserver\fsumanager\vendor\jaspersoft\rest-client\src\Jaspersoft\Tool\RESTRequest.php on line 378

Questions.

Can you access the JRS Community edition from PHP?

The 'organisation' name is not available in community edition, what parameter should be passed?

Any help on why the example script will not run would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What version of Jasperserver do you use? Because as I see the latest PHP client was released in 2014.

Comment: I'm using Japsersoft version 6.  The latest version i could find